# Disable automatic firebase analytics of screen tracks

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-analytics

I've integrated successfully Firebase Analytics for screen tracks and I'd like to disable automatic screen analytics since I don't want to see the native screen classes including `UIViewController` from Firebase Analytics Events table.

- documentation regarding automatic analytics for screens.
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews
- documentation regarding screen tracking with React Navigation.
  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/

Is there any way to disable automatic analytics of screen and enable only manual analytics?